How can I use semantic highlighting in vscode like in pycharm?
is there any way to do this in vscode like in pycharm?
in pycharm in settings ,editor, color scheme, language defaults, semantic highlighting i can choose multiple colors for variables
i can use this
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations" in vscode  but i can set only one color i've tried multiple themes still same
vscode vs pycharm

You may need to install additional extensions to achieve this effect. If you want the official extension python to provide that functionality, you can report it at GitHub.

You need to install the extension "Semantic highlighting" by malcolmmielle.
It gives the variables different colors like the image you have shown.
You can even change the colors that are used for the highlighting in the extension settings.

its buggy when not using coderunner in terminal other than that its perfect. thanks
